# is it possible to copy object (singleton) to data object in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have an object and data class which are implementing the same interface. Is it possible to copy object properties into data class ?

with this declarations:

```
interface ConfigInterface {
    val WINDOW_HEIGHT : Double
}

data class Config (
    override val WINDOW_HEIGHT: Double
) : ConfigInterface


object DefaultConfig : ConfigInterface {
    override val WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600.0
}
```

i would like to do something like

```
newConfig = DefaultConfig.copy(WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What's stopping you from making a `copy` method inside `DefaultConfig` with a default argument for `WINDOW_HEIGHT`?

Comment: I've just figured it out, problem is that there is a lot of arguments in config (WINDOW_HEIGHT is only example) , so I would like to avoid to write them all fourth and fifth time ....

Comment: Data classes have their own copy method, so would it be possible for you to define DefaultConfig as `val defaultConfig = Config(WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600)`?

Comment: yes, but then i lost the convenience of having DefaultConfig as a singleton

Comment: Does it really matter that much, though? What do you need a singleton object for, specifically?

Comment: to create instances of config in different places of the app, sometimes with some changes

Comment: cannot handle via import

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222334/discussion-between-user-and-ts).